How to round off number to one decimal place in C?
I am trying to round off a double to only one decimal place.
double a;
scanf("%lf", &a);
printf("%f", a);

Example 1:

Input: 4.5

Output: 4.500000

I only need 4.5 as the output.


Example 2:
Input: 4.64

Output: 4.640000

I only need 4.6 as the output.

Also, is there any pre-defined function in <math.h> in C that we can use for this purpose?


Have you read some documentation of printf()?

Use %.1f format. The number after . specifies the number of decimal places.

Surely there must be a duplicate for this.

@Student I didn't DV, actually. It's not a bad question, just one I feel must already have an answer on Stack Overflow.

I downvoted. The "question does not show any research effort."

You can also do int places = /* computation or definition */; printf("%.*f", places, a);

You can do it like this:
double a;
scanf("%lf", &a);
printf("%.1lf", a);

If you want to round off a double to only N decimal place, you can use %.Nlf instead of %.1lf .

(The l is optional for printf, but not for scanf.)

Keep in mind that this does not address rounding. Do you want something like 4.790000 to print as 4.7 or 4.8?

@Chris printf("%.1lf", a) does round, as requested. fesetround can partially control how it rounds. If the OP wishes a specific kind of rounding, they should mention that.

There are a few few ways you can go about this. If you want to go the rounding direction you can use round() to achieve it.
double a;
scanf("%lf", &a);

// Round to one decimal place
double rounded_value = round(a * 10) / 10;

printf("%.1f\n", rounded_value);

You can change out the round() for a few things but using printf("%.1f\n", ) is the key.

And if they want to truncate rather than round?

you could use double a;
scanf("%lf", &a);
// Truncate to one decimal place
double truncated_value = floor(a * 10) / 10;

printf("%.1f\n", truncated_value);
return 0; '


Re "And if they want to truncate rather than round?", That would be a different question.

@ShapeShifter42 floor doesn't truncate negative values.
